# Disk Utility: When verifying Time Machine backups, do I need to run First Aid on each volume and container?

Tags: macos, mac, backup, time-machine, disk-utility

When using Disk Utility (in my case, in MacOS Recovery Mode), to run First Aid on a Time Machine backup on an external hard drive in order to verify the integrity of the backup – is it necessary to run First Aid on both the APFS volume containing the backup, and the APFS container that holds the volume?

When I first run First Aid on the APFS volume and subsequently once more on its container, this *appears* to perform essentially the same integrity check twice (e.g. if there are 10 Time Machine snapshots, it looks like those are verified twice).

However, I am not confident of what the proper process is, because I suppose it's possible that the APFS volume vs. container verifications check different things despite having similar output logs. Additionally, I always run First Aid also on the Physical Disk; this appears to perform other verification functions.

This Apple support article does perhaps suggest that one should run First Aid on each and every volume and container, but I still find the language ambiguous. In case verifying the APFS container also verifies the volume, this is very redundant.

https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/repair-a-storage-device-dskutl1040/mac

---

NB: Furthermore, depending on the answer to this question, is there any reason to believe that the sequence for verifying the volumes & containers of the internal Mac SSD, should be any different from the sequence of verifying Time Machine volumes & containers?

[image: Image from support article, regarding verification of the SSD contents]